# "object has no attribute" Error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Below is the code which i have written in the Python tkinter .

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

class UICreation():
    def __init__(self):
        print ("I m in __init__")
        tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

    def tabCreation(self):
        print ("I M in Tab Creation")
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="select ")
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text="Add ")
        self.tabControl.grid()

    def checkBox(self):
        print ("I M in checkBox")
        CheckBox1 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text="Check1")
        CheckBox1.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UICreation()
    ui.tabCreation()
    ui.checkBox()
    root.mainloop()
```

Below is the error

> I m in **init**
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       I M in Tab Creation
>         File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 26, in 
>           ui.tabCreation()
>         File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 15, in tabCreation
>           self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="select ")
>       AttributeError: 'UICreation' object has no attribute 'tabControl'

Please Help me over this . What I am doing wrong and How to resolve it

Comment: You simply need to ask yourself "where do I create `self.tabControl`?"

Comment: @BryanOakley I found the Problem and Solution . I have added the answer below

Answer (score 2):

Your `__init__` method should probably be:

```
def __init__(self):
    print ("I m in __init__")
    self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
    self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
    self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
```

You are missing the initial `self.` for each attribute.

Comment: I did below changes  as suggested ,but still the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
I m in __init__
  File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 25, in <module>
    ui = UICreation()
  File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
NameError: name 'tabControl' is not defined`

Comment: @sreevathsabr Of course, sorry, fixed it now I think.

Answer (score 1):

We must set `tabcontrol`, `tab1` , `tab2` to self and use them with self

Below is the answer to the problem :

```
   import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    root = Tk()

    class UICreation():
        def __init__(self):
            print ("I m in __init__")
            self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
            self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl) #we must use self.tabControl
            self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl) #we must use self.tabControl

        def tabCreation(self):
            print ("I M in Tab Creation")
            self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="select ")
            self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text="Add ")
            self.tabControl.grid()

        def checkBox(self):
            print ("I M in checkBox")
            CheckBox1 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text="Check1")
            CheckBox1.grid()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        ui = UICreation()
        ui.tabCreation()
        ui.checkBox()
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`UICreation` never receives root when it is instantiated. Fix the `self` as well so that it is an instance property.

```
class UICreation():
    def __init__(self, root): #add root here
        print ("I m in __init__")
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)

    def tabCreation(self):
        print ("I M in Tab Creation")
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="select ")
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text="Add ")
        self.tabControl.grid()

    def checkBox(self):
        print ("I M in checkBox")
        CheckBox1 = Checkbutton(self.tab1, text="Check1")
        CheckBox1.grid()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = UICreation(root) # call with root
    ui.tabCreation()
    ui.checkBox()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Still I am facing error `I m in __init__
I M in Tab Creation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 26, in <module>
    ui.tabCreation()
  File "C:/Path/FileName.py", line 15, in tabCreation
    self.tabControl.add(self.tab1 , text="select ")
AttributeError: 'UICreation' object has no attribute 'tabControl'`

Comment: I have updated the answer . It was Not the problem with root .

Answer (score 0):

You should set `tabControl` `tab1` `tab2` to `self`.

```
def __init__(self):
    print ("I m in __init__")
    self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)
    self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
    self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
```